# How can I escape an arbitrary string for use as a command line argument in Windows?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd

I have a list of strings and I want to pass those strings as arguments in a single Windows command line call. For simple alphanumeric strings it suffices to just pass them verbatim:

```
> script.pl foo bar baz yes no
foo
bar
baz
yes
no
```

I understand that if an argument contains spaces or double-quotes, I need to backslash-escape the double-quotes and backslashes, and then double-quote the argument.

```
> script.pl foo bar baz "\"yes\"\\\"no\""
foo
bar
baz
"yes"\"no"
```

But when I try to pass an argument with literal percent signs, this happens:

```
> script.pl %PATH%
C:\Program
Files\PHP\;C:\spaceless\perl\bin\;C:\Program
Files\IBM\Java60\bin;
(...etc.)
```

Double quoting doesn't work:

```
> script.pl "%PATH%"
C:\Program Files\PHP\;C:\spaceless\perl\bin\;C:\Program Files\IBM\Java60\bin; (...etc.)
```

Nor does backslash-escaping (notice how the backslashes are present in the output):

```
> script.pl \%PATH\%
\%PATH\%
```

Also, the rules are inconsistent for backslash-escaping backslashes:

```
> script.pl "\\yes\\"
\\yes\
> script.pl "\yes\\"
\yes\
> script.pl "\yes\"
\yes"
```

Also, doubtless there are special characters in the Windows command line shell, much like there are in all shells. **What, then, is the general procedure for safely escaping arbitrary command line arguments for use at the Windows command line?**

The ideal answer will describe a function `escape()` which can be used in situations like the following (a Perl example):

```
$cmd = join " ", map { escape($_); } @args;
```

Here are some more example strings which should be safely escaped by this function (I know some of these look Unix-like, that's deliberate):

```
yes
no
child.exe
argument 1
Hello, world
Hello"world
\some\path with\spaces
C:\Program Files\
she said, "you had me at hello"
argument"2
\some\directory with\spaces\
"
\
\\
\\\
\\\\
\\\\\
"\
"\T
"\\T
!1
!A
"!\/'"
"Jeff's!"
$PATH
%PATH%
&
<>|&^
()%!^"<>&|
>\\.\nul
malicious argument"&whoami
*@$$A$@#?-_
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an msdn blogpost showing how. It however assumes that every command line program internally uses [CommandLineToArgvW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to parse it's command line (not a shabby assumption, since it's part of the Shell32 library).

Original link (may not work): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/twistylittlepassagesallalike/archive/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-arguments-the-wrong-way.aspx

Web archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20190109172835/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/

Comment: Thank you for this extremely informative link. My question is answered now.

Comment: Of course, this only seems to handle command line arguments. The same procedure doesn't seem to work for escaping the zeroth argument i.e. the name of the program to launch: `^"C:\Program Files\p.pl^"` yields `'"C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103368 hints at the right answer. Although `|` is not possible in filenames, and several other commands are.

Answer (score 4):

To escape a command line *argument*, use the following:

```
sub escapeArg {
  my $arg = shift;

  # Sequence of backslashes followed by a double quote:
  # double up all the backslashes and escape the double quote
  $arg =~ s/(\\*)"/$1$1\\"/g;

  # Sequence of backslashes followed by the end of the arg,
  # which will become a double quote later:
  # double up all the backslashes
  $arg =~ s/(\\*)$/$1$1/;

  # All other backslashes do not need modifying

  # Double-quote the whole thing
  $arg = "\"".$arg."\"";

  # Escape shell metacharacters
  $arg =~ s/([()%!^"<>&|;, ])/\^$1/g;

  return $arg;
}
```

To escape the actual command line *command*, for example when invoking a command with a ridiculous name such as `()!&%PATH%^;, .exe` (which is perfectly legal), use the following:

```
sub escapeCmd {
  my $arg = shift;

  # Escape shell metacharacters
  $arg =~ s/([()%!^"<>&|;, ])/\^$1/g;
  return $arg;
}
```

Note that using `escapeArg()` for the command will not work.

Sources:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/twistylittlepassagesallalike/archive/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-arguments-the-wrong-way.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103368

Comment: Note that technically you do not need to enclose `$arg` within double-quotes (and double the number of trailing backslashes) if `$arg` does not contain blanks.  See [Parsing C++ Command-Line Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx).  I also do not believe that you have to escape shell metacharacters if e.g. you are passing the command line straight to `CreateProcess` and `cmd` is not involved (though in batch files and/or for arguments to `cmd /c`/`cmd /k` you *do* need to escape shell metacharacters.)