# (How) can you pass whitespace as a command line argument in C#?

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

Is it possible to pass whitespace to a C# program as a command line argument?

I am writing a script that parses a text document, and would like to allow users to specify their own separator, rather than hard-coding one.

However, if the separator is a space, then the program appears to discount it as an argument, whether surrounded by quote marks or not.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427732/how-can-i-escape-an-arbitrary-string-for-use-as-a-command-line-argument-in-windo

Comment: if on command line you do `yourProgram.exe "test" " "` then it will receive two arguments, one `test` the other one `" "` which is space, This should work.

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.CommandLine` will give you the complete command line, including any whitespace. Although I think it would be tricky for your users to pass tabs or line breaks. I'd suggest having them pass the char code(s) for the separator(s) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

[Escape command line arguments in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510343/escape-command-line-arguments-in-c-sharp)

From what some other similar questions say, using Regex seems to be the way to go.

(Not really done much C# I'm afraid, but just saw this on the homepage)

Answer (score 1):

you can pass in quoted whitespace "    "
For example

> FileParsing.exe arg1 "   " arg3 "some other arg"

Comment: This gives me an IndexOutOfRangeException - i.e. it thinks it's only had 3 arguments, not 4.
(I explicitly count the arguments, to give the user feedback if their input is missing something, and it definitely has issues with " ".)

Comment: It worked here for me. I'm on Windows 7 and running the standard cmd.exe